# What is the default height on Androids TabLayout

Tags: android, layout, tabs, height

Seems like something that should be easy to find, but it's harder than I thought.
What is the default height on the TabLayout in DIPs?

Comment: how to set it to default height, I hate adding lot of custom heights as per different screen resolutions

Comment: @ShirishHerwade If you set the height to wrap_content in xml, then it will automatically size to the default height. If you want to explicitly set a height, then set height to 48dp in xml.
    Using dp sizes it based on screen resolution.If you're trying to set the height dynamically, then you'll have to multiply your height by a float based on screen resolution. 
    You can get the screen resolution using the line:
    getApplication.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

Comment: Thanks wrap_content works

Comment: https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Material Design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs) state that this height equals 48dp when You have text **or** image, and 72dp when You have image **and** text.

Answer (score 1):

its height is **"?attr/tabIndicatorHeight"**

E.g.
 you can use this value in an xml file for another view like:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/tabIndicatorHeight"
```

And it will look  ok on all devices.

Comment: This is marked as deprecated: `Instead, set the intrinsic size of the custom drawable provided to the tabIndicator attribute in order to change the indicator height. For example, this can be done by setting the <size> property in a <shape> resource.`